# Animate SVG with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm currently testing different options to animate SVG files directly in the SVG file. Right now I'm testing animations with included JavaScript. The problem is, I don't get a proper rotation around the origin working.

My code is currently looking like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve">


<g>
    <g>
        <path class="bag" fill="#016D49" d="M42.1,45.6c-6.7,0-13.5,0-20.2,0c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3c0.4-6.9,0.9-13.8,1.3-20.7c0-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.3
            c5.9,0,11.7,0,17.6,0c0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3c0.4,6.9,0.9,13.8,1.3,20.7C42.4,45.5,42.3,45.6,42.1,45.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#016D49" d="M27.8,23.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.9-5.3,4.1-5,4.2-5c0,0,3-0.3,4,5c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.8H38
            c0-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8c-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.6-2.1c-1.2-3.1-3-4.7-5.4-4.6c-3.6,0.2-5.1,3.8-5.6,6.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.1,0.8
            L27.8,23.1L27.8,23.1z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="loadingRing"> 
    
        <circle  fill="none" stroke="#016D49" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="7.0201,7.0201" cx="32" cy="32" r="26.8">
           
    </circle>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var zpos=0;
function turnAround(){
zpos++;
    if(zpos>359)zpos=0;
    var dz=document.getElementById("loadingRing");
    

    dz.style.transform = "rotate("+zpos+"deg) translate(1%,1%)";
    
    window.setTimeout("turnAround()", 14);
}
turnAround();
</script>
</g>
</svg>
```

So what am I missing, or does a better solution exist? Maybe it is possible to include jQuery in the SVG file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should stick to normal SVG tools and not over complicate things for something as trivial as a rotation.

It wasn't clear to me what you want to spin, so I made them both spin:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve">

<g>
    <g>
        <path class="bag" fill="#016D49" d="M42.1,45.6c-6.7,0-13.5,0-20.2,0c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3c0.4-6.9,0.9-13.8,1.3-20.7c0-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.3
            c5.9,0,11.7,0,17.6,0c0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3c0.4,6.9,0.9,13.8,1.3,20.7C42.4,45.5,42.3,45.6,42.1,45.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#016D49" d="M27.8,23.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.9-5.3,4.1-5,4.2-5c0,0,3-0.3,4,5c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.8H38
            c0-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8c-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.6-2.1c-1.2-3.1-3-4.7-5.4-4.6c-3.6,0.2-5.1,3.8-5.6,6.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.1,0.8
            L27.8,23.1L27.8,23.1z"/>
    </g>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="360 32 32"
                          to="0 32 32"
                          dur="10s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</g>
<g id="loadingRing"> 

        <circle  fill="none" stroke="#016D49" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="7.0201,7.0201" cx="32" cy="32" r="26.8">

    </circle>
  
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 32 32"
                          to="360 32 32"
                          dur="5s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

Here you go, a version with scripting, impractical, but since you wanted it...

```
dz.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + zpos + " 32 32)");
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve">


<g>
    <g>
        <path class="bag" fill="#016D49" d="M42.1,45.6c-6.7,0-13.5,0-20.2,0c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3c0.4-6.9,0.9-13.8,1.3-20.7c0-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.3
            c5.9,0,11.7,0,17.6,0c0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3c0.4,6.9,0.9,13.8,1.3,20.7C42.4,45.5,42.3,45.6,42.1,45.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#016D49" d="M27.8,23.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.9-5.3,4.1-5,4.2-5c0,0,3-0.3,4,5c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.8H38
            c0-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8c-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.6-2.1c-1.2-3.1-3-4.7-5.4-4.6c-3.6,0.2-5.1,3.8-5.6,6.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.1,0.8
            L27.8,23.1L27.8,23.1z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="loadingRing"> 

        <circle  fill="none" stroke="#016D49" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="7.0201,7.0201" cx="32" cy="32" r="26.8">

    </circle>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var zpos=0;
function turnAround(){
zpos++;
    //if(zpos>359)zpos=0;
    var dz=document.getElementById("loadingRing");


    //dz.style.transform = "rotate("+zpos+"deg 32 32)";
    dz.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + zpos + " 32 32)");

    window.setTimeout("turnAround()", 14);
}
turnAround();
</script>
</g>
</svg>
```

Notes:

1. I couldn't make it work with changing the style property. Not sure why.
2. You don't need to reset from 359 to 0. Degrees are anyway computed mod 360.

Comment: i know the animate tag, but i want to try out all possible solutions for svg animations, to do a browser test with all of them and check their compatibility. I've tried the animate and also css transofmrations within the .svg file.